# Php Sanitize and Validate form with some character exceptions

Tags: php, regex, validation, sanitize

I'm using in Php Sanitize and Validate Filters but I have problems to add some rules, I have some basic knowledge of php so I think this question is easy for you.

```
if ($_POST['ccp_n'] != "") {
            $ccp = filter_var($_POST['ccp_n'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            if (!filter_var($ccp, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                $errors .= 'Insert a valid code.<br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Insert a code.<br/>';
        }
```

I need to add a minimum and maximum number of characters (14-15) and I want to accept this characters ( - or space ) .The exact sequence is 0000-0000-0000 (the last four digits could be 5 too

Thanks

Comment: "Something like" is a bit vague. Define the variable length and the positions of the hyphen in the string a bit more. Besides the hyphen should only digits be allowed?

Comment: Yes, only digits. The exact sequence is 0000-0000-0000 (the last four digits could be 5 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` and apply a regular expression.

`preg_match ( string $pattern , string $TestString)` [See here in detail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

The pattern is the problem. You need to define in detail what is allowed.

For example, the pattern:

```
'~^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4,5}$~D'
```

would be the whole string from start `^` to the end `$`. 4 digits, hyphen, 4 digits, hyphen, 4 to 5 digits.

**See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2um1g)**

**Update:**

I added the `D` modifier to the end, otherwise the `$` not only match to the end of the string, but also before a newline as last character in the string. [See here for php modifiers in detail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Don't forget the `/D` modifier.

Comment: @Geert, thank you for teaching something new. updated my answer.

Comment: In this case, applying to my example, I will use FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP with this regular expression. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Alternatively, you can also use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) to parse the input from a string according to a format.